# How to read files from directory path in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def serve_file(data,address):
    print sfile
    for filename in os.listdir(some/where/documents):
        print sfile
        with open(os.path.join(some/where/documents,data),"r"):
            s = fin.readline()
            while s != "":
                time.sleep(3)

serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.27', 9090))
print "\nServer is listening..."
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the code you've shown doing, and what do you want it to do instead?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a way to get a list of files from a directory? You might be looking for a "glob". A glob gets a list of files matching some pattern, which may also contain a path:

```py
from glob import glob

# will be a list of all files ending in .txt
files_list = glob('/some/path/*.txt')

for fname in files_list:
    f = open( fname, 'r' )
    for line in f:
        print line
```

More info. here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html